# after_create destroy a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback, after-create

I have two tables bookings and rentals. A user books a car to rent and an admin approves the rental.

As the admin approves the rental. The booking is no longer needed. How can i delete the booking record at the same time as creating the rental record.

this was my attempt (i'm new to ruby so apolagies if i am being stupid)

```
#rental_controller.rb
after_create :delete_booking

def delete_booking
  @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  @booking.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to rental_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
```

Comment: It looks like you ar trying to do too much in one method and breaking mvc.  Is the snippet from your model?  If so, the respond_to belongs in the controller not the model.  Maybe try rephrasing your question because I don't quite understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @John i have tried my best to re-phrase the question. It's quite hard to work

Comment: I added an answer of what I think is wrong.  What is the relationship between rental and booking (has_many, belongs_to, has_one, none)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After create belong in the model, not the controller.  I'm assuming you have a rental model since the snippet is from the rentals controller.

In the rental model:

```
after_create :delete_booking


def delete_booking
  @booking = Booking.where(:booking_no => self.booking_no).first
  @booking.destroy
end
```

Comment: booking_no is the relationship between booking and rental

Comment: Rental and Booking have a column called booking_no? Updated my answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to *delete* the booking, just mark it completed. It's pretty rare in real-world applications that you want to completely remove a record as though it never existed. If there's a problem with somebody's rental, suddenly it's their word against yours that they had booked it on such-and-such a day for such-and-such a model of car.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally something like ..

```
# Booking.rb Model

has_one :booking
```

And

```
# Rental.rb Model

belongs_to :booking, :class_name => "Booking", :foreign_key => "booking_no"

after_create :delete_booking

private
  def delete_booking
    self.booking.destroy
  end
```